# MySQL bug causing server crashes

Tags: mysql, crash

So from reviewing my MySQLd error log, the problem is

```
101210  4:33:30 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
101210  4:33:30 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
```

Once this happens, mysql will crash. It's a known bug which can be viewed here - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35346

But does anyone know how to fix it? I don't see a patch anywhere on there or how to fix this issue.. Am I blind? I really need to fix this so my server can stop crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are **blind**
that bug is marked as duplicate bug of http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46385

Get yourself upgrade to version 5.4.2 as stated in the bug 46385

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should apply values from its defaults